# Changin a textview text each time clicking a button

Tags: android, android-studio, button, textview

Hi I Want To Change TextView Text Each Time I Click A button.
For e.g. first Click It Change the text to "Hi"
Second Time "Bye"
Third Time "Again ?"
And Make It A loop.
How Can I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```java
int count =0;// Global Variable 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Button btn =findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(this::when_clicked);
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.text);
}
//when_clicked funtion

public void when_clicked(){
String  set_text;
if(count%3==0) set_text= "Hi";
if(count%3==1) set_text= "Bye";
if(count%3==2) set_text ="Again";
txt.setText(set_text);
count++;
}
```

Comment: It worked Tnx, Just how is `count` increasing ?

Comment: in the end of the function when_clicked() , it increase each time you click on the button by one .

Comment: @Pam Ix hi, what is the "3" in each of the "if(count%3==x)" lines?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something?

You can accomplish it by using a counter and a list of strings.
Here's a starting point:

```
int counter = 0;
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

// populate your list
messages.add("Hi there");
......
......
......

// set the click listener
myButton.addOnCLickListener(v -> {
    if(counter >= messages.size())
        counter = 0;
    
    myTextView.setText(messages.get(counter));
    counter++;
});
```